# profile image access forbidden

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I have created a custom **customer attribute (profile_image)** when I display it in the profile page it throws error

> Forbidden You don't have permission to access
>   /media/customer/1/0/100876954-Untitled-2.240x240.jpg on this server.
>   Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at 192.168.1.243 Port 1208

but this media folder have the **0777 permission**.

and the  error log have mention the following error

lient denied by server configuration: `/home/vhosts/FederalLawyer/app/etc/local.xml`

Comment: Did you also check file permissions for the subfolder (/media/customer/...)?

Comment: i checked with this case and it have 0777 permission .

Comment: please check .htaccess in media folder also. It helps some one

Answer (score 0):

- /www/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php

Line 50+-

```
'directory_mode' => 0755,         
'file_mode' => 0644,
```

- /www/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/DriverInterface.php

Line 20+-

```
const WRITEABLE_DIRECTORY_MODE = 0755;

/**
 * Permissions to give read/write access to owner and owning group, but not to all users
 */
const WRITEABLE_FILE_MODE = 0644;
```

- SSH magento root

  find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;

  find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
- clear var folder
- run setup:upgrade
- run static-content:deploy

Sorry for the fast answer , not much time atm but this works for me.
Also i have no idea if this is even a good answer security wise but its what my host recommends